# how to swipe multiple images fetched from a data using react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using rails as a backend to communicate with the ios app(react-native).
I need to be able to swipe images one by one and accumulate view counts.
I am hoping to use Swiper which is a react-native component to achieve this matter. Need some guidance! thank you